# Setter is not fired if value having white/empty spaces in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

I am developing an application in Xamarin.Forms platform. In that, I found one issue in c#. If we try to set a value which is having empty/white spaces to a CLR property I am having in my application, the corresponding property's setter is not fired.

```
public string Name
{
    get => _name;
    set
    {
        _name = value;
    }
}
```

If I try to set a value like this, Name = "ABC   ", then the setter of the above property is not fired. FYI, I am using .NET 2.0.3 library.

Is this a known issue or am I missing something?

Comment: How do you call the property setter?

Comment: Name = "ABC ". Like this, I am setting value for the property.

Comment: What do you mean "the corresponding property's setter is not fired" exactly? Can you describe the exact behavior you are experiencing and what you were expecting?

Comment: How are you setting it to empty

Comment: For example, if I set Name = "ABC   ", the setter of the property "Name" is not fired. So the value of the "Name" property remain "null" instead of "ABC   "

Comment: Could you show the full class and where you use the Set and the Get?

Comment: How are you observing that the value remains null? Are you step debugging through the code and watching the variable in the watch pane? Or are you making an inference based on other program behavior, such as program output? The example you provided, in which a variable is simply assigned a value, is not helpful in understanding the issue, as there is obviously nothing intrinsically wrong about it..